# Is this question "If we can't write a unit test then what is the closest solution?" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, questions, phrase-choice

I'd like to know whether the question

> If we can't write a unit test then what is the closest solution?

grammatical? Does it sound natural or may be you would ask that kind of a question some another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is grammatically correct.  Whether it could be understood depends on what a "unit test" and a "close solution" are.

My understanding of the jargon is that a "unit test" is a computer procedure that tests one aspect of a computer program.  It's not clear how a "solution" could be close to a test, so that doesn't seem to be understandable. Perhaps you meant

> If we can't write a unit test, what is the best option?

or

> ... what should we do instead?

Comment: Thank you! You've got it right. I just want to indicate that I need something close, not very different from a unit test - so I ended up with the phrase "closest solution"...